# Can't get Silverstripe tests to display results

Tags: php, phpunit, silverstripe

I've added some tests to a new Silverstripe project, they reside in `app/tests/` (`app` is what I have renamed `mysite`, `_config.php` has also got this in it's `$project` variable).

I have two files:

**APHPUnitTest.php**

```php
class APHPUnitTest extends SapphireTest {

    static $fixture_file = 'APHPUnitTest.yml';

    public function testURLGeneration() {

        $expectedURLs = array(
            'home' => 'home',
            'about' => 'about-us'
        );

        foreach($expectedURLs as $fixture => $urlSegment) {
            $obj = $this->objFromFixture('Page', $fixture);
            $this->assertEquals($urlSegment, $obj->URLSegment);
        }
    }
}
```

**APHPUnitTest.yml**

```yaml
Page:
    home:
        Title: Home
    about:
        Title: About Us
```

The test appears on `/dev/tests`, however When I run it, I just see the header:

```
APHPUnitTest
dev → tests → APHPUnitTest
```

and no results... I can add `die;` to my test `.php` and these stop the page from loading, so the file is executing fine, I'm unsure as to why this isn't working.

When I attempt to run the test from command line I get the error `class SapphireTest not found`. Non-silverstripe PHPUnit tests run from the command line work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue, however there were two things that were causing it so I thought I'd put them both here in the hope that it helps somebody else.

The main issue I was having here was related to database permissions. The database user I was running the tests as only had permissions for the Silverstripe site in question. Tests require the user to be able to create a separate database for each test. Granting sufficient permissions fixed my issue.

The other thing that needed to change was my `phpunit.xml`, it still read `mysite/tests` when it needed changing to `app/tests`.